A Lagrange interpolation question
Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional complex vector space which is acted on faithfully by a finite group $\Gamma$. Suppose $\Gamma' \subset \Gamma$ is a proper subgroup. Fix a vector $v \in V$ such that its isotropy group under the $\Gamma$-action is a subgroup of $\Gamma'$.
Question: is it possible to find a polynomial $p_v: V \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ such that: (a). for any $\gamma' \in \Gamma'$, we have $p_v(\gamma'v) = 1$; (b). for any $\gamma \in \Gamma \setminus \Gamma'$, we have $p_v(\gamma v) = 0$; (c). the coefficients of $p_v$ depends polynomially on $v$ if we vary $v$ under the same condition?

To be precise, what do you mean by a polynomial is this context? A matrix entry?

You can say it's an element in the direct sum of Sym(V*)

@ShaoyunBai  what  Sym(V*) stands for, and what direct sum do you mean?

@PietroMajer: it's the (graded) symmetric algebra over the linear functionals, i.e. the algebra of polynomial functions over $V$.

@ShaoyunBai First two conditions are satisfied by the Lagrange interpolation polynomial. The last condition is not specified correctly. Coefficients with respect to what basis? What do you mean by varying $v$ under the same conditions? That the isotropy subgroup is the same?
